# Masonry jquery - not satisfy with the results

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm discovering Masonry and trying to use it for my website.
The ultimate goal would be to have something as smooth as 500px.com or something similar.
so far I've played with Masonry and tried to follow the tutorials and the advises of this forum which are very helpful ! - thanks

now this is what I got: http://www.thejunglemurmurs.com/tags3.php
But unfortunately it is not as nice as the tutorials and I'm a bit disappointed...
I was expecting a better filling of the container, now I see a lot of holes.

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
width: 1000px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.masonryImage {
  float: left;
  background: #BBBBBB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  width:180px;
}

.col1{width:180px;}
.col2{width:280px;}
.col3{width:380px;}
.col4{width:480px;}
.col1 img{max-width:180px;}
.col2 img{max-width:280px;}
.col3 img{max-width:380px;}
.col4 img{max-width:480px;}   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <?
    $i=0;
// pics is filled with the number of the picture from SQL
    while (isset($pics[$i])){
       $pic = $pics[$i];
       $j = $view[$i];
       echo "<div class=\"masonryImage col$j\"><img src=\"http://www.thejunglemurmurs.com/photos/$pic.jpg\" alt=\"\"></div>";
       $i++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
<script src="http://www.thejunglemurmurs.com/js/jquery.1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.thejunglemurmurs.com/js/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js">   </script>
<script>
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know if there is anything I've missed here or if there are some guidelines to fill up properly the container will the pictures (square pictures, ratio between columns...)

Answer (score 0):

Your grid needs to be set to a fixed size in Masonary and your elements need to be controlled.

look at 500px and see the the height is all the same set at 500px height (that is why its called 500px I think..)

So each line is 500px.. but some pictures are half size of 250px so they fit nicely.
I looked at your example and all pictures are various sizes- so it tries very hard to arrange it but the grid is all over the place.

```
 var gridSize = 500;
 widgets.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.Widget',
        columnWidth: GridSize
    });
```

And then you have to make sure that your DIVs are not larger than 500 or multiples of 500 ie. 125px,250px,500px,750px ...  then it will fill in nicely. Obviously it can be any size you need but engineering it is up to you only and from my experience a bit tricky.. but once it works it is great.

It is a great plugin and I think there is also an [option](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html) to force aggressive sorting or automatic resizing if gaps exist.